# Why doesn't chloride cause high blood pressure?

Tags: biochemistry

Assuming osmotic pressure is the (main?) culprit, why isn't the chlorine ion loose in your body after eating salt considered equally responsible for hypertension?

I have searched Google and Wikipedia, and cannot find an answer.

I have looked here at Stack Exchange, too.

Why is it that you always hear about how bad 'sodium' is for your diet, but every sodium cation comes with a chloride....

Could someone point me to an article, at least?

Comment: I made an important change to your title: chlorine -> chloride. The latter is the anion in salt, which is presumably what you're interested in. The former may cause high blood pressure via a horrific death.

Comment: what have you done to answer this question? this will inform community on how to help you

Comment: What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Not every sodium comes with a chloride ion.  For instance sodium bicarbonate (baking soda), sodium nitrate (in preserved meats), monosodium glutamate (Chinese food), and many more that are used in food (or sometimes medicines).

Comment: Boy, so many people are obsessed with how much OPs research..

Answer (score 1):

Osmotic pressure is not the main mechanism of sodium-induced high blood pressure.

> high dietary salt raises cerebrospinal fluid [Na(+)]. This leads, via the Na(+)-sensing circumventricular organs of the brain, to increased sympathetic nerve activity (SNA), a major trigger of vasoconstriction

[How NaCl raises blood pressure: a new paradigm for the pathogenesis of salt-dependent hypertension.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22058154)